# Can't guess the "obvious" plane equation from 3 points

Tags: real-analysis, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve this question which has left me stumped. The previous part of the question gave us this graph:

[image]

It asked to *quickly guess* what is the linear equation of the line which passes through both $(0,3)$, $(0,0)$, which is immediately $x=0$.

Right after, as if to use that question as direction, we are asked, once again, to *quickly guess* the equation for a plane which passes through $(9,0,0), (0,5,0)$, and $(0,0,3)$. I don't know how to guess this immediately without having to calculate the system of equations to get $5x+9y+15z=45$.

What am I missing? What intuition have I failed to carry over from the previous question?

Comment: The answer given by @Quanto is correct, and is probably the quickest way to find the equation of the plane, but I'm as mystified as you are as to how you should have developed any intuition for his method from the previous question. If they had first asked you for the line going through $(2,0)$ and $(0,3)$ -- which you could quickly see should be $x/2 + y/3 = 1$ -- it would make much more sense. I almost wonder if someone made a mistake when assembling your text and put in the wrong example for the first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the plane intersects with the $x, \>y, \> z$-axis at $9,\>5, 3$, respectively. Thus, the equation takes the form
$$\frac x9+\frac y5 + \frac z3 =1$$